# executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList: Bad Access Exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

I am facing this crash exception, in my app.

Below are crash details, in the logs it is directly pointing to the FMDatabase class:

```
FMDatabase.m line 664 -[SF_FMDatabase executeQuery:withArgumentsInArray:orDictionary:orVAList:] 

Crashed: fmdb.<SF_FMDatabaseQueue: 0x170427840>
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000006458
```

Comment: That's not enough information.  Assuming `FMDatabase` isn't broken, it's the use of it that is causing the crash.  Therefore we need to see how you are using it.

Comment: Stripped code specific details from question.